# Does casting affect result of instanceof operation?

Tags: java, object, instanceof

I'm confused.

Say we have the following classes:

```
class Shape { /* ... */ }
class Square extends Shape { /* ... */ }
```

what are the resulting booleans, and why are they so?

```
Shape shape = ...;
boolean b1 = shape instanceof Square;

Square square = ...;
boolean b2 = ((Shape) square) instanceof Square;

boolean b3 = shape instanceof Object;
```

From what I know, a subclass is an instance of a parent, but not the other way around?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your question to make it actual Java code - please update if this doesn't accurately reflect your question.

Answer (score 8):

In this code:

```
Number n = new Integer(42);
```

`Number` is the *apparent type* of `n`, while `Integer` is its *real type*.

*Casts* change the *apparent type*, while `instanceof` checks against the *real type*.

As a consequence, casting has no effect on `instanceof` results.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the [language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2):

> At run time, the result of the `instanceof` operator is `true` if the value of the *RelationalExpression* is not `null` and the reference could be cast to the *ReferenceType* without raising a `ClassCastException`. Otherwise the result is false.

So `instanceof` is unaffected by casts: it's checking if the *runtime value* can be cast; the runtime value itself is unaffected by a cast, all it does is to tell the compiler to "trust you" that the type conversion is safe.

So, the three booleans are:

- `b1`:

  - `false` if you assigned `shape = null`;
  - `true` if you assigned `shape = new Square();`
  - `false` if you assigned `shape = new Shape();`, or any other subclass of `Shape`.
- `b2`:

  - `false` if you assigned `square = null`;
  - `true` otherwise, as the cast doesn't create a "new" `Shape`.
- `b3`:

  - `false` if you assigned `shape = null`;
  - `true` otherwise, as every non-null instance of a reference type can be cast to an `Object`/assigned to a variable of type `Object`.